# Trying to create an app with while loops

Tags: android, eclipse, multithreading, while-loop

I'm a complete newb. I'm trying to port this simple program I made in class to an Android app. It's just suppose to print out " I love Computer Science!!" a certain amount. But I'm suspecting the while loop is causing my program to automatically force close. I've searched and found that I need to make a thread, but I can't find a similar situation.

Here's my onCreate method:

```
public void onClick(View v) 
     {
int number = 1;
int printed = 0;
int limit = 0;
int count = 0;


String countString;
second.setText("How much do you love Computer Science?");

countString = howMuchEditText.getText().toString();
count = Integer.valueOf(countString);

printed = count;

while ((count -1) >= limit)
{
   third.setText(+number + " I love Computer Science!!");
   count -= 1;
   number ++;      
}
fourth.setText("This printed " +printed + " times.");
     }
    });

}
}
```

Could anyone help me fix my force close?

Comment: Please ad an error log if you want to receive an exhaustive response

Comment: This app definitely does not need threading. And I don't think Andrew is getting ANRs, he is getting Force Closes. So what is probably happening is that he didnt initialize one of the text views, or the parsing of the string is failing and he isn't putting it into a try/catch block.

Answer (score 0):

Android only allows your application's handlers five seconds to execute before you'll get an "App not responding" message. Depending on the loop count, your `onClick` method could easily exceed that limit.

If you want to display an automatically updating counter, you will need to launch an asynchronous task that executes in the background.

[Here is a quick tutorial](http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/05/android-asynctask-example/) on `AsyncTask`, but you will need to learn more about the fundamentals of the Android platform before it will make sense. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To add to the previous answer, AsyncTask is not quite the answer either. This is because your modifications of the TextView cannot be done on a background thread—UI calls are only allowed on the main thread. To schedule periodic tasks on the UI thread, create yourself a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) object, which has various `post` methods you can call to run tasks after a specified interval, or as soon as possible.